# How to check an object collision with an another object multiple time in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, collision

I am making a feature that make sound when green box collision with grey box (as the first image). I using OnCollisionEnter2D to play sound, and it play one time when they collision (in the second image) as I expected but as the third image, it played sound 3 times in same time and I want it only play one more time, how can I avoid this? Thank you

[image]

My code here is just a log to check it in editor

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    Debug.LogError("PlaySound");
}
```

I want it play just two times, when in second image and third image

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. I have reconstructed your scene and I only receive two messages, one for each corner making contact. Consider that at a high velocity your box might bounce a little and trigger another collision event. You could test this theory by printing the [relativeVelocity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision2D-relativeVelocity.html).

Comment: @Voidsay thank you for reply, I added another log in OnCollisionExit2D and I saw OnCollisionExit2D and OnCollisionEnter2D trigger at the same time 2 - 3 times, I thought it was bounced and I set a 2d material with bounciness = 0 to both collider and rigidbody but it still trigger OnEnter and OnExit at the same time.
But thank you for reminding me relativeVelocity, I can use the magnitude and delay to skip the unnecessary play sound time :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is likely due to multiple collision events being detected in quick succession. To avoid this and ensure that the sound plays only once per collision, you can implement a mechanism to limit the sound playback to once per collision event rather than using magnitude and delay to skip it

Something like this would do the work

```
private bool hasCollided = false; // track if collision sound has been played

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (!hasCollided)
    {
        // Play the sound

        // Set the flag to true to prevent further playback until reset
        hasCollided = true;
    }
}

private void ResetCollisionFlag()
{
    hasCollided = false;
}
```

the sound effect will only be played the first time the collision occurs, and subsequent collisions during the same interaction won't trigger the sound again until you reset the hasPlayedSound to false. Better than using delay.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank for your help, Gyan. But I need it still play sound in the second collision, then it will be more real. 
It's hard to describe it, but you can understand that the edges of the green box will make sounds when impacted and I don't want to create more collider inside.